# How to reset color properties of Microsoft Heirarchical FlexGrid?

Tags: vb6, mshflexgrid

I have an MSHFlexgrid in a legacy VB6 application that the users want to set various colours in. I've sorted out applying the user colours but I need to add a reset option as well. However I'm getting an overflow error when attempting the following line:

```
grdUserData.BackColor = vbWindowBackground
```

The same code works fine on other other controls I've used it with but errors with the MSHFlexGrid. The actual value of `vbWindowBackground` is `&H80000005` or `-2147483643`.

I tried reading the `BackColor` property of another control but that has the same underlying value and thus also causes the same error.

How can I get the actual BGR/RGB (or long) value used for the control rather than the preset which I'm assuming is part of a look up for the color at runtime?

While it's easy enough to estimate what the right color is for some controls for the current Windows theme I need to get the right color for the current theme regardless of what the current theme is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
Private Declare Function GetSysColor Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Private Function BgrColor(ByVal Color As Long) As Long
    If Color >= 0 Then
        BgrColor = Color
    Else
        BgrColor = GetSysColor(Color And &HFFFFFF)
    End If
End Function
```